# NSNotificationCenter re-executes notifications

Tags: swift, swift2, nsnotificationcenter

I am using NSNotificationCenter to set a variable shared when a notification comes in across 3 TableViewControllers (all subclassed from the same class).

All works fine except for the following scenario:

The user is in the main view (the view that actually processes/responds to notifications) when the app goes to the background (e.g. user presses Home button). If a notification comes in and the user launches the app either from the icon or from the alert the app behaves as if it needs to process not only the last notification but also all the notification up-to-now.

For example: let;'s assume that the app processed 5 notification already. The app moved to the background and then a notification came in. The user launches the app from the icon which causes the app to move to the foreground. The app will trigger 1 action per notification.

This is not the case if the user was in any other screen before the app moved to background. However, if the user moved to the main view, the notification was processed and the app moved to background again, on the next notification, the app will process 7 notifications (the 5 we had + 1 previous + 1 current).

While conceptually it seems as if my app is spawning n-observers, it is not clear to me why. I set an observer in the base class in `viewWillAppear` and remove in `viewWillDisappear` (also tried a `deinit` block - no change in behaviour).

Any idea why the observer accumulate all notifications? Is this the normal behaviour for an observer? If so, how do I remove 'observed and processed' messages?

Comment: I am under the impression that it would help a lot if you also post some code + logs

Comment: Trying two things: 1. using specific removeObserver (as oppose to remove all). 2. calling removeObserver before addObserver. 3. adding a UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification observer allowing me to remove observers when app moves to background.

Comment: remove the notification observer at one point in your app.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was to remove the observer before adding it.

The problem itself came down to the fact that the order of cleanup (i.e. add observer in viewWillAppear, remove observer viewWillDisappear) did not match my expectations. The result was that the observer was being added again and again but the corresponding 'remove' did not actually 'happen'.

I guess it was due to the fact that adding/removing observers took place in the base class (and not sub-class).